# DHTMLX : Refresh a grid with loadXMLString()

Tags: dhtmlx

I want to use the method loadXMLString() to refresh the content of my grid.

I founded this, but this is not working for me :

http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=11382

So I tried this :

grid._refreshFromXML =[true,true,false];
grid.loadXMLString(".....");

Again, not working !

Any ideas ?

I suppose the problem is with the line "grid._refreshFromXML = ..."

Thanks a lot !

I'm working with DHTMLX 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use 
grid._refresh_mode =[true,true,false];

There is no _refreshFromXML function in the grid.